# Fluent Bit 1.8+ and MULTILINE_PARSER

Tags: fluentd, fluent-bit, efk

My goal is to collect logs from Java (Spring Boot) applications running on Bare Kubernetes.
These logs are then translated into ES and visualized in Kibana.

For these purposes I deployed Fleunt Bit 1.8.9 via Kubernetes 1.22. Since I use Containerd instead for Docker, then my Fluent Bit configuration is as follow (Please note that I have only specified one log-file):

```
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Flush         1
        Log_Level     info
        Daemon        off
        Parsers_File  parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server   On
        HTTP_Listen   0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port     2020

    @INCLUDE input-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE filter-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE output-elasticsearch.conf

  input-kubernetes.conf: |
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/*.log
        Read_from_head    true
        Parser            cri

  filter-kubernetes.conf: |
    [FILTER]
        Name                kubernetes
        Match               kube.*
        Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
        Kube_CA_File        /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        Kube_Token_File     /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
        Kube_Tag_Prefix     kube.var.log.containers.
        Merge_Log           On
        Merge_Log_Key       log_processed
        K8S-Logging.Parser  On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude Off

  output-elasticsearch.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name     es
        Match    kube.*
        Host     ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}
        Port     ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
        Index    kube-code_index
        Type     kube-code_type

  parsers.conf: |
    [PARSER]
        Name cri
        Format regex
        Regex ^(?<time>[^ ]+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr) (?<logtag>[^ ]*) (?<message>.*)$
        Time_Key    time
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z
```

With this configuration in Kibana, the Java stack trace messages are displayed unstructured:
[image]

But I need the Java stack trace to be structured like in the screenshot below:
[image]

I tried a configuration like this:

```
  input-kubernetes.conf: |
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/*.log
        Read_from_head    true
        Multiline.parser  cri, multiline-regex-cri
```

And:

```
parsers.conf: |
    [PARSER]
        # http://rubular.com/r/tjUt3Awgg4
        Name cri
        Format regex
        Regex ^(?<time>[^ ]+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr) (?<logtag>[^ ]*) (?<message>.*)$
        Time_Key    time
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z

    [MULTILINE_PARSER]
        name          multiline-regex-cri
        type          regex
        flush_timeout 1000
        #
        # Regex rules for multiline parsing
        # ---------------------------------
        #
        # configuration hints:
        #
        #  - first state always has the name: start_state
        #  - every field in the rule must be inside double quotes
        #
        # rules |   state name  | regex pattern                  | next state
        # ------|---------------|--------------------------------------------
        rule      "start_state"   "/(\D+ \d+ \d+\:\d+\:\d+)(.*)/"  "cont"
        rule      "cont"          "/^\s+at.*/"                     "cont"
```

But all the same, the logs are not structured:
[image]

Please help me structure the logs.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem too. If you use multiple parsers on your input, fluentbit tries to apply each of them on the same original input and does not apply them one after the other.

When you have multiple multiline parsers, and want them to be applied one after the other, you should use filters, in your case it would be something like that:

```
[INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/*.log
        Read_from_head    true
        Multiline.parser  cri

[FILTER]
        Name                  multiline
        Match                 kube.*
        multiline.key_content log
        multiline.parser      java
```

I can see in your screenshot, that you are trying to parse java stacttrace, for that you can use build-in `java` parser, so you do not need `multiline-regex-cri`.

Comment: any suggestions if INPUT is Name tcp or forward?

Comment: help you a lot ! it works